Dealing with extreme values for outliners in a boxplot: cutting the y-axis
When making boxplots, I have to deal with extreme outliners that are making my boxplot look bad (exemple: the mean value for one specific variable is about 600, but there are some outliners of about 95,000, what is making my y-axis not properly scaled and flattening the boxplot enough to turn it into a line).

I'm using the following code to try to fix this problem, but I always get back the error: "Error in Ops.data.frame(guide_loc, panel_loc) :
‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames".
# Create the plot for 'cost_val'
box1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = gender, y = cost_val, fill = gender)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.3) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 20, size = 2, color = "navy", position = position_dodge(width = 0.3)) +
  labs(x = "Gender", y = "Price") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("F" = "lightsteelblue1", "M" = "lavender")) +
  scale_y_break(breaks = c(2000, 30000)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(r = 20)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 20)),
        legend.position = "none") +
  theme_minimal()

# Create the plot for cost_val
box2 <- data %>%
  filter(card_use == "yes") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = gender, y = cost_val, fill = gender)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.3) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 20, size = 2, color = "navy", position = position_dodge(width = 0.3)) +
  labs(x = "Gender", y = "Price") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("F" = "lightsteelblue1", "M" = "lavender")) +
  scale_y_break(breaks = c(2000, 30000)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(r = 20)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 20)),
        legend.position = "none") +
  theme_minimal()


# Arrange plots in a grid
grid.arrange(box1, box2, ncol = 2)


Can't figure out where is the mistake...
But the point is, log2 scale did not work as I expected because it made the y-axis marks uneven and akward.

I've tried to use scale_y_break() differently but the code never works.
Any ideas of how I can deal with the y-axis' scale for my plot?

Have you tried a logarithmic scale? For instance, scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10") instead of setting the breaks.

Welcome to SO, Julia! This question about how to deal with outliers in ggplot boxplots may be helpful for your situation.

This might be an appropriate place for scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 1000), which would blend a linear scale with a log scale, transitioning around 1000.

If you like the idea of a log scale, but you want your y-axis marks to be even, could you try log-transforming your data rather than the axis?
